# How to browse fonts in Windows?

Tags: truetype-fonts

I got a pack of Windows fonts and they are .ttf files

My question is how can I easily browse those fonts, if possible without copying them in the 'C:\Windows\Fonts' folder?

My purpose is to find a few bold fonts that look better than Impact. I don't need the rest of them so I need to browse them in order to find the best fonts for my task

Answer (score 2):

You can Preview your custom fonts from the folder where they are downloaded.
You right-click and **Preview menu** option:
[image]

You can also enable **Preview pane** and observe there:
[image]